# LibreOffice finds my fonts, but they are not showing correctly

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, 19.10

I'm having trouble using fonts with LibreOffice. They appear as an option in the fonts-list, but they are not displayed correctly. I've uninstalled them (removed from all directories) and verified they are not showing up in menus. I've had them installed in different directories (`~/.fonts/`, `/usr/share/local/fonts/`, `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/nnn/`) but to no avail. I have run `fc-cache -r -v`.

I have run out of options here. The fonts work fine in Scribus and in other applications, but not in any LibreOffice applications.

Running Ubuntu 19.10 with LibreOffice 6.3.4.2.